# UIActivityIndicatorView Between Table Views

Tags: ios5, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an iPhone app that starts in a table view and goes to a different table view when the user selects a cell. The two table views are in separate classes (or whatever the proper Objective-C term is, ie. 2 different .h and .m files), and the second table view makes a request from a server based on the selection in the first table. There is a noticeable delay and I've been trying to put a UIActivityIndicatorView up when that happens, but that only displays for a split second when view segues to the second table view. I know this is an issue with threading, but I can't get this to work following any of the other posts on this topic. I call my startAnimating in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and the stopAnimating in the viewDidDisappear. I have also tried using the following code to get this to work by calling it in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: [activityIndicator performSelectorInBackground: @selector(startAnimating) withObject: nil];  How do I make the activity indicator (or any loading animation for that matter) to work when the server request is going on?

Comment: I'm not sure of this answer, but maybe you should call the stopAnimating method after the other table has finished loading?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I don't think you can do that because the activity indicator is a class variable and not a global.

Comment: I see that this is a frequent problem on Stack Overflow, but I did just find a working solution. I found this forum http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/82536-using-uiactivityindicatorview-when-performing-long-synchronous-tasks.html My issue was a synchronous connection taking up my main thread, so starting the spinner and then calling the connection in a separate method does the trick. My rep is too low, so I will update this as the answer after 8 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that this is a frequent problem on Stack Overflow, but I did just find a working solution. I found this forum iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/… My issue was a synchronous connection taking up my main thread, so starting the spinner and then calling the connection in a separate method does the trick.